# Switching languages on appengine

Tags: google-app-engine

Consider a case where an appengine project was done in PHP, but is now being completely replaced by a Go rewrite (not a new module/version, but complete rewrite and no need to maintain the old PHP version).

Is it ok to deploy the new project over the existing one, or is it better to delete the existing project and creating a new one (it's not really a public project yet, and in any case it is served via custom domain- assume downtime isn't a concern)?

My specific concern is that there might be some cached junk from the PHP version, and in general I'd like to understand a bit better of what deploying actually does- is it like rsync and deletes from remote if the file isn't local? Along with the codebase I'm also concerned about old static folders etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly fine switching to another language for a new version of an app (i.e., without using a new app id). Older versions, in the prior language(s), are available until either you delete them manually, or deploy enough new versions in the new language that the older versions age out.

As long as you change the version, there's no issue with cached junk.

Comment: what happens if I don't change the version (i.e. "version" field in the app.yaml)?

Comment: Try it in a scratch project and find out :)

Comment: Well I mean, even with the live project- it works, but what happens to all the old "junk" like that? is it deleted or does it somehow consume storage/memory/load?

Comment: That's an interesting question. AFAIK, if there are lingering, inaccessible bits of stuff, that's an internal issue for App Engine.